# Make Facebook App Visible on Page

Tags: facebook

As the creator of a canvas app on facebook I have been able to add the app to one of my pages. However the public can not see it on my page and other page owners are met with an error message when provided with the link (`https://www.facebook.com/dialog/pagetab?app_id=112111718948734&display=popup&next=https://dry-savannah-3512.herokuapp.com/`) to add it to their page.

The app's status is:

"App Detail Page Status: Live
Your app detail page is now live and will appear in Search.
App Center Listing Status: Unlisted
Your app is not listed because it does not have enough high ratings and user engagement to be listed in the App Center at this time. Please refer to your app's Insights page to view your app's user rating and engagement metrics, and view our App Center guidelines for more information."

Will this error go away if I link a bunch of people to use the app? How many would that need be?

Thanks

Chris

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Are you sure the app isn't in Sandbox Mode? This is by far the most likely reason a page tab would be visible to the page admins but not other users.

Next most likely is the app which runs the page tab being restricted by age or location; the admins will still see if even if they don't meet the restrictions

Comment: Thanks for the timely feedback igy.

Comment: Thanks for the timely feedback igy.
I can confirm that the app does have sandbox mode "on"
it is appearing to me (admin) on 2 of my pages but not others still. I havent set up any restrictions on these pages.
When i directly link people the app it says page not found. Although the app works for me.

Comment: Yes, this is because you have sandbox mode 'on', turn it off

Comment: Wow, had completely overlooked this
many thanks. All working now!